# programming language for managing/auto-organizing (media) files in windows?

Tags: powershell, batch, python, java, file-management

I hope this question is in the right stackoverflow site.

I have built a massively complex batch script set for managing files. It unpacks, renames, adds subtitles, does mp3 gain, figures out where the file needs to be placed into according to the words in the filename by applying scores to each word. It also searches for duplicate files using size, duration and parts of the filename. It uses a wide range of prompt executable tools like filebot, mkvtoolnix, mp3gain, 7z and many others. I have also built a sort of user interface for it, which is very painful to use and uphold.

I realize how ridiculous it is to build a massive program like this out of batch scripts but it's the only language I know. I really, really need to start this 16 year project from scratch and rewrite it in an actual programming language. What language would be the go-to one to learn for this type of project with a proper GUI?

I only know batch and html so keep the lingo simple please.

Comment: which site would be the right one for this? please??

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell. Everything you do in batch and cmd line is almost 1 to 1 transferable into PowerShell. I suggest executing the batch files individually in the PowerShell ISE to discover & correct any errors, but they should all be fairly easy to overcome. After that it should be just as simple to connect it all in HTML.

Comment: how will it help though?

Comment: "proper GUI" and "PowerShell" don't go that much hand in hand as VB or C# would. However, this is primarily opinon-based.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have very much personal experience with it, but I've heard that one of the easiest ways to make a graphical application (especially one that has file interactions), would be programming it using the .net framework in combination with C#.

However, before you learn a whole new language (and a whole new framework), you should probably consider if learning a new language (and then later completely re-writing your scripts for that language) is really worth it. On the other hand, you may find, like I have, that a language like what you are looking for will be useful to know in the future.